# How to limit filter for sub report graph in crystal report..?

Tags: filter, charts, crystal-reports, formula, subreport

I’m new to crystal reports and I’m using crystal report 11. I have created a crystal report with a sub report and that sub report filtered by 2 user parameters named “EMP_NAME” and “EVALUATION_YEAR”. Within the sub report I insert a group and in group footer I insert a chart. That chart filtered from above 2 user parameters and from group parameter.

The problem is I need to filter my sub report from “EMP_NAME” and “EVALUATION_YEAR” while filtering my chart only from “EMP_NAME” and GROUP PARAMETER.

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi.  See the [FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the question topics for Stack Overflow.  I think your question is more suited to the sister site http://superuser.com/.

Comment: What is the grouping field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requirements:

- subreport displays one employee
- subreport displays one year's of employee data
- subreport includes a graph of all years' of employee data

Solution:

- Create an `{?Employee Name}` parameter in the the main report; link it to `{TABLE.EMP_NAME}` in the subreport
- Create an `{?Evaluation Year}` parameter in the main report; create an `{?Evaluation Year}` parameter in the sub-report; link two parameter fields; DO NOT LINK TO DATA.
- Create a graph in the sub-report that will display all years' data (for said employee); place in `header` section
- In the sub-report, insert a group on `EVALUATION_YEAR`; suppress footer; create conditional formula to suppress header if `{EVALUATION_YEAR}<>{?Evaluation Year}`; suppress `details` section.